# Enforcing a limit on ERC721 tokens held by an account

Tags: solidity, erc-721

We are providing a Gnosis multisig wallets to our users and a market place where users can purchase/sell/transfer ERC721 tokens with other users. The ERC721 contract will also have a Blacklist registry in which all the addresses will be put, who were trying to be nostalgic. 
New addresses can only be added/removed by an Admin multisig wallet.

We want to limit our users to possess, lets say only 10 tokens at a time. We have come up with two possible solutions but couldn't decide which is the best for this problem.

1 .We monitor every transfer/mint/burn event on our contract and maintain cumulative balances offchain. These cumulative balances will be updated with every transaction and the admin will put an address in the Blacklist if this address was trying to breach the imposed limit.

2 .Make use of balanceOf mapping in ERC721 standard. Every transfer will check this mapping and refuse to execute a new transaction if the token limit is breached. Will this change the ERC721 standard?. This will also not take account of cumulative ERC721 tokens, A user purchases and then transfers his/her token to some other dummy addresses repetitively to avoid the token limit.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is when you say a user can not have more than n tokens, that should essentially mean an address can not hold more than n tokens in smart contract world. So talking about the solutions. For simplicity let max no of tokens a user can hold is 10.

**Solution 1:** This is very much dependent on taking steps after the requirement is violated. SO say a user had 10 tokens and he purchased 11th token, an admin will blacklist this address but the user already has 11 tokens. Either admin had to revert that which will require your contract to overpower admin and admin can revert any tx. Also when admin sends a tx to blacklist, and other transfers are made it will cause a race condition, so I could send a high gas price and send 10 more tokens to the address before the admin's blacklist tx is included in a block. Also since someone else can send tokens to your address, anyone else can send you tokens knowingly or unknowingly and make you blacklisted, which is a bad design. So IMO I don't think solution 1, is good enough.

**Solution 2:** This seems a more accurate solution as in this case, you won't allow users to have more than 10 tokens at any cost when user purchased the 11th token, the transaction will fail. So this mitigates the issue and not blacklisting defaulters. Also no manual action is involved from the admin's end for blacklisting.

And about a user can have multiple addresses to hold more than 10 token is possible with both the solutions.

Comment: And this approach will not violate the ERC721 address?

Comment: No, this doesn't violate the ERC-721 standard. But this limitation can cause other platforms might have to code some extra bit of change in their platform to support your ERC-721.

Comment: You mean, limitation that some transfers will fail ?       Other platforms would have to make provision for this exception?

Comment: Limitation that transfer will fail. Like I have a platform that provides trading of 721 assets via smart contract, Now If I had to integarte you coin, I will have to make sure no user can place 3 buy txs, because they will fail and no one wants to spend money on txs that will likely to fail. Like these there are other cases. But if that is your business requirement, you can do that.

Comment: Can a new mapping be kept in a storage to keep track of token limit of addresses? The token limit of different addresses is different and will be updated by admin..

Comment: Depends if you have the concept of imposing different restrictions to differet users, you can use mapping to maintain maxTokenBalance. Each time admin whitelists the address, he can provide a limit to save function for updating the limits

Comment: One last question, I was just wondering if this is a common practice?
Is there any other platforms that have implemented the same strategy?
I have seen some platforms which allows more tokens to be held only when they complete their KYC, How do they impose such a limit or they all are custodian wallets?

Comment: I personally don't follow many platforms, but I don't this is a common practice. Because at the end, a user can create multiple accounts and hold 10 tokens in each. You are just making it difficult for a user. Talking about a platform, since a user can have only one account on platform, so no one can own more than 10 tokens on given platform but not in general.